# How to Filter data based on two property in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contain some data like this:

```
Name | LName
------------
John| Snow
Raymond | Redington
....
```

I can search in each column with the following code

```
list.ShapeView().Where(p =>
                         (p.Name.IndexOf(autoBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1) ||
                         (p.LName.IndexOf(autoBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)).Apply();
```

If I type the following text, the results will be filtered correctly

- John
- Snow

But if I type both of them together

- John Snow

no result will be displayed, how can I implement this?

Comment: What is `Apply`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ShapeView is extension method https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/11/30/wpf-using-linq-to-shape-data-in-a-collectionview/

Comment: You need an array of names : string[] names {"John", "Snow"};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want to support. If you also want that only part of the `TextBox.Text` must be contained in either `Name` or `LName`, then this should work:

```
var query = list.ShapeView()
    .Where(p => autoBox.Text.IndexOf(p.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  != -1
            ||  autoBox.Text.IndexOf(p.LName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
            ||  p.Name.IndexOf(autoBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  != -1                         
            ||  p.LName.IndexOf(autoBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
```

You could also split on spaces and search the first token in `name` and the second in `lname`. But this is also broken, what if someone types "John Lee Hooker"? What is the first name and what is the last name? So you should have two Textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can aplly `Split` to text and use the `function Contains`

Example:

```
string[] valores = autoBox.Text.ToUpper().Split(' ');

var query = list.ShapeView()
    .Where(p =>valores.Contains(p.Name.ToUpper())||valores.Contains(p.LName.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: The code is great, but if a name is 2 words like (name: seyed Mahdi, lname: hosseini), there is a problem